# Is a capacitor bad when it looks like this?

Tags: capacitor, troubleshooting, damage

Hello I am new to the electronics field. I am looking inside of one of my synthesizers and I see some capacitors (I think they are Mylar, correct me if I'm wrong) that look like this. I know it is a bad sign if an electrolytic capacitor is bulging, but is it the same on these?

Is there anything wrong with these capacitors?

The issue I have is that the brass sound disappears over time after you turn the synth on. It starts with high volume but it slowly goes down in volume and sometimes it disappears completely.

The other problem is that there is bleed between the higher and the lower part of the keyboard. The keyboard is split in the middle. The sounds come from 5 different presets that you can turn up and down for the higher and the lower part of the keyboard. But if you turn for example the strings up in the higher it also plays a bit in the lower and vice versa.

I have studied the schematics and diagrams over the past week and only now did I discover that a significant amount of the electrolytic capacitors are not the same value as what it should be according to the schematic. But it is always a higher capacitance and higher voltage. But I don't know if the schematic is wrong or if there are wrong valued capacitors on the board.

[image: Capacitors inside a synthesizer]

Comment: `is there anything wrong with these capacitors?` ... impossible to answer without taking measurements..... `do these capacitors look defective?` ... no they do not

Comment: Please ask question about your real issue. I guess you look inside of you synthesizer because it does not work properly, not because you like faulty parts?

Comment: I just wanted to know if they looked faulty. The issues i have is that the brass sound dissappears over time after you turn the synth on. it starts with high volume but it slowly goes down in volume and sometimes it dissappears completely. The other problem is that there is bleed between the higher and the lower part of the keyboard. The keyboard is split in the middle. The sounds come from 5 different presets that you can turn up and down for the higher and the lower part of the keyboard. But if you turn for example the strings up in the higher it also plays a bit in the lower and vice versa.

Comment: That outside is the shape they from dipping them in the coating material during manufacture. If it was cracked, there might be a problem. What are those silver-coloured components, e.g. the one at the right edge of the photo with "K5" on it?

Comment: Looking to your other post about TOM synthesizer I propose do not do anything with it unless you have good knowledge in the Soviet electronic stuff. I will contact my friend who is a master in reviving such stuff to see if he is interested in your case.

Comment: It is the electrolytic capacitors. They are from the K50 range which is a notoriously bad soviet capacitor. But i dont know if i should change them.

Comment: Does the device work? If yes, then no issue. If not, start troubleshooting and if it boils down to the capacitors, it’s desolder, LCR meter and compare to rating.

Comment: The device works apart from the issues i stated up above with the brass and the bleed.

Comment: Ah! Please edit the original question. Sprinking extra information in the comments is frowned upon here.

Comment: Alright im new here, sorry.

Comment: No worries! Your question has got a close-up picture and clear English, so you have a good start to stand on.

Comment: The chosen "best" answer doesn't answer the asked question *"Is a capacitor bad when it looks like this"* -- the chosen answer answer's the asker's "real" question about troubleshooting his synthesizer, so the question ought to be changed to actually ask that.

Comment: I agree @Johnny the suggestion should be verified before accepting. But the time delay clue does suggest a thermal issue somewhere. The Mylar caps look normal, as do the metallic cased solid tantalum electrolytics.

Comment: Should i edit my original post so it better reflects the actual thread? for future reference at least?

Comment: Originally what i was looking for were just a judgement of the capacitors but all of a sudden it evolved from there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since this a heat related problem, as everyone has stated it is probably an electrolytic capacitor which is more than likely true. The best way to test for the heat related capacitors is with a can of circuit cooler. Canned Air Dusters will work very well if turned upside down. Allow equipment to warm up and volume has gone down. Then spray some capacitors in one area of the board, allow a few seconds for the coolant to take effect. If you have hit the right one the volume will return. If not select another area to cool four or five capacitors.
When finding the right area allow it to warm up again, then selectively spray one at a time each capacitor, allowing time for it to take effect. When you hit the right one, replace it. Some cases may have several capacitors bad.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didnt even think of doing troubleshooting that way. I will try this for sure :)

Comment: Do you have any recommendations as to what circuit cooler spray to use? Preferably one that is relatively cheap and can be bought in the EU

Comment: I used some compressed air and it was a 1:1 effect. Thanks a tonne for this advice. Now i have located the board on which the fault resides. But i dont know if the bleeding issue has got anything to do with heat.

Comment: The bleeding is feedback through the power supply because of inadequate filtering, ( i.e. Capcitors) It must be Canned Compressed Air Dusters - Walmart: It has to be turned upside down to get liquid which will freeze your hand off if you try it. Otherwise you will have to find an electronics parts store to get circuit cooler.

Comment: To test non heat related capacitors, use jumper wire attached to an external capacitor. I usually use a small capacity, higher voltage capacitor to test with. Turn off power unless experienced. Hook up leads to bottom of board. Check polarity and location. Turn power back on. If no effect, remove, touch 2 leads of cable together to discharge, turn off, hook up, test, repeat as needed.

Comment: Alright i will recap the power supply, the filters and maybe the other boards (chorus, LFO and delay line) and then i can see if these problems dissappears. thanks for the advice

Comment: "Canned Air Dusters (...) turned upside down" - just keep in mind that it means you're spraying liquid propane, which is basically a flamethrower waiting for ignition.

Comment: 1,1-Difluoroethane, liquefied, under pressure, Note: Commonly referred to as refrigerant HFC-152a   Auto-ignition Temperature >454 °C [849 °F]      (Auto-ignition Temperature)
Ignition temperature is defined as the minimum temperature to which a material must be heated to cause the production of free radicals (bond breakage). If this process occurs in the presence of oxygen or some oxidizing agent, combustion will take place.

Answer (score 8):

The film caps look fine, but barring something really destructive (unlikely with such a part in this application) they usually do.

The electrolytic caps dry out over time, power supply caps first generally because they are hotter (every 10'C halves the life). You usually can't tell by looking at them either (newer applications they sometimes bulge). Soviet-era parts are old enough to be faulty.

To test you need an ESR meter, and a chart of approximate expected values. It's usually possible to check in-circuit with a good such meter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm talkikng about the k50-12 capacitors. The degradation of these capacitors can lead to a strong distortion of all modes of operation of the electronic circuit in direct current, which can cause a total inoperability.

I would advise you the following rule:

1. Download the documentation and schematic diagrams:

   http://www.ruskeys.net/base/1501tom.php
2. Start by replacing the electrolytic capacitors in the power supply (if you have an oscilloscope, the indicator of degradation is the presence of 50 Hz on the power buses)
3. Replacement of electrolytic capacitors in the synthesizer modules:

   1. The operating voltage of the new capacitors should not be less than the equivalent voltage indicated on old capacitors
   2. If the capacitor shunts the supply circuits (see schematic diagrams), the capacitance may be larger than the capacity of the original capacitor. If the electrolytic capacitor is in frequency-setting circuits, it is desirable to install a new capacitor with the same capacitance

I think no other substitutions are needed.

P.P.S. One from my instruments after replace all of electrolytic capacitors - works fine

[image: polyvox synth]

Comment: It also has a lot of K50-24 capacitors. are they equally bad? I know that soviet gear arent of the highest quality but surely, some of the components must still be fine

Comment: I have studied the schematics and diagrams over the past week and only now did i discover that a significant amount of the electrolytic capacitors are not the same value as what it should be according to the schematic. But it is always a higher capacitance and higher voltage. But i dont know if the schematic is wrong or if there has been placed wrong value capacitors inside it.

Comment: @SørenHansen `But it is always a higher capacitance and higher voltage.` If the capacitors are electrolytic, and they're used for power supply, or similar application then, in general, it's allowed to make such a replacement. Basically, they were putting in capacitors of higher quality than needed, which can make sense in some cases, when for example, there's an oversupply of a certain type of capacitor, or it could be that the schematic is not the newest version, and there were reliability issues discovered later.

Comment: Yeah that sounds plausible. But just out of curiosity: What would happen if you placed a capacitor with a higher capacitance on a circuit where it mattered? You know, not a power supply or similar application but somewhere where it is important that the capacitance is the same as the one youre replacing? sorry for my bad english, im not a native speaker

Comment: @SørenHansen The only mistakes in that last comment are: 1.   "what would happen" should not be capitalized (it's not the start of a new sentence).  2. "Sorry" should be capitalized; 3. "English" should be capitalized; 4. "I'm" needs an apostrophe and a capital I.  All of those are very common mistakes for native speakers.  The only way I can tell you aren't a native speaker is the last clause.

Comment: I'll write again. All the changes in the work of "old" devices made in the space of the former USSR are associated with degradation of the operating modes of the nodes by D.C.

In 99 cases out of 100 this is due to the degradation of electrolytic capacitors, the quality of which simply was not calculated for such a long lifetime of the electronic device. They "dried up", there was a big leakage in the current in the circuit, disrupting the cascade operation mode.

Comment: As I already wrote to you above - start by replacing the electrolytic capacitors in the power circuits, then analyze all the critical points in which electrolytic capacitors are also used (replace them with at least cheap Chinese ones first) - and your tool will work for the same amount of time

Comment: https://vk.com/topic-536310_14228407?post=3508
(You can use Google Translate)

Answer (score -3):

At first, You need to change ALL polar (electrolytic) capacitors. These components are very degraded, and at the moment you can consider them defective (inoperative). I talk about axial aluminum capacitors

Comment: But there are over 200 of them. 190 of them sits under the keys and i think they just operate the functionality of the keys and the keys are fine. i have ordered the capacitors for the power supply and i will recap that. But i dont know if i should recap the other boards such as filter, delay line, oscillator etc.

Comment: Why do you say they are very degraded? And why change *all* electrolytic caps?  You don't fix things by just replacing all capacitors.

Comment: "the keys are fine" - except you said you had bleed from one half of the keyboard to the other, which might be caused by electrical leakage through the caps. (Possibly this is actually going on all the time, but you only notice it when you use the split keyboard option).

Comment: @MCG agreed you don't necessarily fix things **just** by replacing all caps. On the other hand, if you know the electrolytic caps are poor quality components and well past their sell-by date, you might as well replace all of them now, rather than spend time testing them, replace the faulty ones, and then repeat the test-and-replace every few months in future until you *have* replaced all of them!

Comment: @alephzero indeed it is a good idea to replace old caps. I was merely commenting on the context of the answer which is basically saying 'replace all caps and job done'.

Comment: The bleed is on at all times. the strings have the highest amount of bleed. the piano bleed is negligible. But i dont know if that is because of the keys (is it typically that or what?). The reason i am leery of replacing all the sliders is because it would cost me around 300€ in parts and most of the boards are a hassle to solder on because they are hardwired together.

Comment: (I goofed up reviewing edits on this post - for some reason I thought the changes added were from the OP (in which case they wouldn't be in the edit review queue!). So I did a rollback to before the edit. If those changes were made by user astronomer, kindly edit them back in by using that same account. You can find changes to the post under edit history. If the changes were added by someone else: post your own answer instead.)